# How to initialize custom ActiveModel Validators in Rails 3+ app from within a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I'm trying to load some custom Validators from a Rails Engine but my application keeps failing due to the validator not being recognized.

What is the proper way & time to initialize the validators in the engine?

For example I have:

```
    class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      # Validates whether <tt>value</tt> is <tt>nil?</tt>.
      def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        record.errors.add(attribute, :not_nil) unless value.nil?
      end
    end
```

From within my engines class `Engine < Rails::Engine` I have tried a few different ways to initialize the custom validators such as:

```
config.before_initialize do
  class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  end
end

config.after_initialize do
  class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  end
end

initializer 'ab_gem.validators' do |app|
  ActiveSupport.on_load :active_model do
    class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    end
  end
end

initializer 'ab_gem.validators' do |app|
  ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
    class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    end
  end
end

initializer 'ab_gem.validators' do |app|
  class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  end
end
```

I also tried moving these into a custom module to load, but none of these methods are initializing / loading properly.

Anytime my applications model is being loaded I receive `Unknown validator: 'NullityValidator'`

Comment: What is the error that this is giving? I don't think defining them as empty classes in the initializer is going to do you any good, as it won't go looking for the "real" code for the validators.

Comment: I receive Unknown validator: 'NullityValidator' since the validators aren't being loaded before the models using them.  I'm not actually defining them as empty classes in my code.  I wanted to provide brief snippets of how I was attempting to define the classes for brevity.  The entire validator definition is at the top.

Comment: Could it be that you're just not requiring the file anywhere?

Comment: No the lib/ab_gem/engine.rb file where I'm trying to define these is being required and everything else works fine.  I thought I would be able to initialize these validators there with the other initializers I have, but it just isn't working.  I also tried to move them to their own file and require it, but I haven't had any luck with that either.  I think the key may be to find the appropriate place within the initialization chain to hook into, but I'm not sure what that would be yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was incredibly more simple and elegant than I thought...  Just create a `config/initializers/` folder for your initializers, and drop the validators there to be loaded in the proper order.

So just made:

```
config/initializers/validators.rb
```

Drop in your validator:

```
class NullityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # Validates whether <tt>value</tt> is <tt>nil?</tt>.
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, :not_nil) unless value.nil?
  end
end
```

Then your good to go.  I was under the impression defining an initializer within your engine.rb railtie would accomplish the same thing, but apparently not.  This is much cleaner and better practice in my opinion anyway though.

Comment: You could also create these initializers and have them load files from a directory such as `your_engine/validators`. The reason for this is that I wouldn't *expect* validators to be in the initializers. It's library code so it should go in `lib`.

Comment: Works nicely in Rails 4 as well!

Answer (score -2):

I am working on a project that has an **email_validator** that was previously working until we moved it to a mounted engine. Now it is saying that the email_validator cannot be found. Should I just copy the email validator class and put this in the **config/initializers/validators.rb** or is there a better method

Comment: don't ask a question in an answer or you won't ever have an answer :)